# Output next 35 days from input date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to print the next 35 days of a particular date.
Here is my function:

```
$randomdate = '01-01-2015';
$a=0;
while($a<35){
 $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($randomdate)));
 $a++; 
 $randomdate =   $date; 
}
```

But this prints only 30 days . Its does not get incremented to next date if month changes.
Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Just use `strtotime("01-01-2015 +35 days");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
<?php
$start_date = '25-02-2016';
$number_of_dates = 10;
$dates = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$number_of_dates;$i++){
  $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$start_date +$i days"));
  echo "\n".$date;
  $dates[] = $date;  
}
?>
```

Check here : https://eval.in/539120